# Exceed installation Error

Tags: windows

Hi i install Exceed got error message: "Error 1317 :an error occured while attempting to create the directory c:/programdata/hummingbird/ connectivity/12.00/global/exceed ". Anyone suggest me how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a permissions problem! Have you set the permissions for the /global/exceed folder?
If so, then depending on the OS you might need to reboot :)

Hope it helps!